# count multiple columns with same ID

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to count the number of rows matching `1` in both the `NUM` and `ID` column

```
 +-----+-----+------
| NAME | NUM | ID
+=====+=====+=====+
| SAM  |  1  |  1
+-----+-----+------
| BOB  |  1  |  1
+-----+-----+------
| JAKE |  0  |  1
+-----+-----+------  
| JOHN |  1  |  1
```

here is what i got so far

```
SELECT `NUM`, `ID`, COUNT(*)
                      FROM `store`
                      WHERE `NUM`='1'
                      OR `ID`='1'
                      GROUP BY `NUM`, `ID`
```

this is what i'm getting right now (obviously using my real data, not the sample table above)

```
NUM     ID  COUNT(*)    
0       1   2
1       0   1727
1       1   28
```

basically i want know the number of rows in NUM that are equal to 1, and ID equal to 1

**so NUM should give me 3 rows and ID should give me 4 rows**

any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Modify your query to use AND instead of OR

```
SELECT `NUM`, `ID`, COUNT(*)
                  FROM `store`
                  WHERE `NUM`='1'
                  AND `ID`='1'
                  GROUP BY `NUM`, `ID`
```

Comment: i get `1|1|28` is should be `3|4` where NUM is 3 and ID is 4.

Comment: @user2636556 What you're aiming for is better achieved with two seperate queries..

Comment: yeah that's what i thought. i have 7 columns tho which means 7 queries. Thought there might be an easier way :)